# Unable to get worksheet the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction Class error

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

[image]

```
Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()  'Badge Number
On Error GoTo Err
Dim tbl As ListObject, fndStr As String
Set tbl = Sheet9.ListObjects("EmployeeList")

fndStr = Trim(Me.TextBox2.Value)
MsgBox fndStr
If fndStr <> "" Then
    Me.TextBox3.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(fndStr, tbl, 2, False)    '<-- Error Line
End If

Exit Sub

Err:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

I have a table named as "EmployeeList" and I am doing simple vlookup using Badge number but I am getting the error for unknown reason. I know there are similar questions asked before but I did read before posting this.

As you can clearly see the table name in the image and Entered value that is `10` for the first parameter on vlookup function but it doesn't returns any value but gives error. Don't know what's wrong.

```
  'I tried this as well
    Me.TextBox3.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(fndStr, Sheet9.Range("A1:F" & Rows.Count), 2, False)    '<-- Error Line

  'And this
   Me.TextBox3.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(fndStr, Sheet9.Range("EmployeeList"), 2, False)    '<-- Error Line
```

Also for unknown reason I can't do

```
    Application.Vlookup as well

    Like when I do Application.V

    Vlookup doesn't shows up in the list.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues.

The first, you have tried to solve, is that you need a `Range` as `Arg2`in [Vlookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194701.aspx). Since your `tbl` is a `ListObject`. you could simply use `tbl.Range`, see [ListObject.Range Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839404.aspx).

The second is, that `Vlookup` will not find strings in a column of numbers. And your first column is a column of numbers. So you need to convert the string into number.

```
Me.TextBox3.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(fndStr), tbl.Range, 2, False)
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code below, i have used evaluate method to get vlookup result.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()

Dim fndStr             As String
On Error GoTo Err_Desc

        fndStr = Trim(Me.TextBox2.Value)
        MsgBox fndStr
        If fndStr <> "" Then
            '// Using Eval method
            Me.TextBox3.Value = Evaluate("=VLOOKUP(" & fndStr & ",EmployeeList[#All],2,0)")
        End If
        Exit Sub

Err_Desc:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```